# Testing multiple conditions (at a newbie level), don't understand how the result came to be

Tags: python

This is my first entry, so sorry if it is not in the style and detail as it is supposed to be(?) Using python 3,6, run through Spyder.
I am a newbie at this, and trying to learn basic if-elif-else blocks. Now, I thought I understod what is going on underneath the hood so to speak, but this code-block had me fooled. I was expecting no output, because I didn't give the code an else statement, but instead it takes a seemingly random answer, making the code unpredictable. I would really appriciate it if somenone could explain to me why the answer ended up being like below, so I don't keep making the same mistake!

**#The first one works fine when I give the expected values, and gives no output when given a random value( any other color than the three below). I can't figure out why this one works, and not the second one.**

```
alien_color = ("red")

if alien_color == "green":
  print("You just earned 5 points!")
if alien_color == "yellow":
  print("You just earned 10 points!")
if alien_color == "red":
  print("You just earned 15 points!")
```

**#The one below does not work when I give it a "random" value (like blue)**

```
alien_color = "blue"  

if alien_color == "green":
   value = 5 
elif alien_color == "yellow":
   value = 10
elif alien_color == "red":
   value = 15   
print("\nYou just earned: " + str(value) + " points!")
```

**When I run this and enter a color different than green, yellow or red, The output prints "You just earned 10 points!"
Why & how did the output become 10 points?**

Just tried to write in a random word that I know I have never used with python as a value for alien_color, and it seems like the output is just a reptition of the last real output, So if I had the color green and printed the 5-point phrase, then it is the 5-point phrase that shows up later. Like it did with the 10-point phrase before, because yellow was the last color I had used to run the code before entering the value blue instead.
So i figured that out, but why it happens I still don't know.

Comment: You probably set it elsewhere before running this code.

Comment: No, and i wrote it in to a new file just to check, still comes out as the 10-point phrase.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean, you wrote it to a new file? and what happens if you print the value before the ifs?

Comment: If you want advice on how to write better questions on SO: Try to put yourself in the shoes of whoever reads this. You start your question by writing about the code as if the reader had already seen it. But the code comes much later. Try to order it in a way which makes sense to the reader. Also you could try to remove irrelevant text from your question. Always try to think what information is really important to someone who wants to answer your question and remove everything else. More people will be willing to actually read your question

Comment: You ran the code before and 'value' has been set to 10. When you set alient_color = "blue", 'value' haven't been changed. 
You should declare starting value of 'value' explicitly

Comment: Thanks for clearifying! It's the little things that get you in the beginning.

Comment: In the first portion of your code there is no variable defined and you directly print something to the console whereas in the second portion you defined a variable value and set its value only in three cases noted above otherwise value will not be set and will give compilation error (try to set it with a value before checking the three cases).